# How can I fix the "foxing" of a shoe?

Tags: maintenance

I left my shoes in my backyard, then somebody let the dog out and part of the shoe died (sad story). Now my parents are making me fix the shoe, is there any "replacement for the foxing?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont know what tags are there for this one

Comment: Can you post a picture of the damage you need to fix?

Comment: There are no tags, because this is not about arts or crafts :) I'd try asking this at [Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/). I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: See [What are Arts and Crafts?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/141).  This question isn't really within the site's scope.  But glad you got an answer.  I suspect your parents' demand to fix it is to turn this into a life lesson rather than an expectation that it is actually fixable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most realistic fix is to buy a new pair of shoes...

If you **must** fix this somehow, be aware from the very first second that it will never look new or professional again and will probably break again very quickly.

First you need to cut away all the losee strands and pieces. The heel could probably be repaired with construction silicone (preferably white). I suggest applying several thin layers and rebuilding and sculpting the heel that way. You can shape the fresh silicone with your fingers if you dip them into a glass of water with lots of dish washing liquid.

The upper edge is pretty much a lost course. You could try hiding the damage by sewing on a new bias tape, but since some material is chewed away, it will always look bumpy. I would be **very careful** when sewing through so many layers. The needle bight break. Maybe glueing the bias tape on is the better solution.

That being said, whether you try to fix them or not, you'll probably end up replacing them very soon anyways.

Comment: wow, this helps me a lot, thanks! ps. the needle already broke

Comment: Gorilla glue actually helped me here